# How can I verify the user passwords in Django

Tags: python, django

Here a method that written inside the class in Django for handiling the post requests.

```
def post(self,request):
    form=self.form_class(request.POST)

    users=User.objects.all()
    if form.is_valid():

        username =form.cleaned_data['username']
        password =form.cleaned_data['password']


    return render(request,"quiz/logged_view.html",{'users':users})
```

There is username and password coming throught the form. How can I verify the password for a user? Thank You

Comment: Have you read the documentation yet? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/default/#auth-web-requests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just get the user with the specified username and then you can use the [`.check_password(password)`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.check_password) method of the User class.

```
user = User.objects.get(username=username)
if user.check_password(password):
    # do stuff
```

Keep in mind that if there is no user with the specified username, it will raise a DoesNotExist Exception.